# How to get a list of objects that's currently in Local View?

Tags: python

So, I know that I can check if the object in local view by using

```
C.object.local_view_get(space)
```

But the problem is this bug: https://developer.blender.org/T95197

Is where another way?

Please note that target `space` might be hidden

The most close solution is to get visible object by

```
objects = [ob for ob in bpy.context.view_layer.objects if ob.visible_get(viewport=space)]
```

But object may be hidden in local view, so this is not an ideal

Comment: Hello ! Just to be sure, local view is when you press numpad . on the keyboard to hide all objects but the selected and zoom viewport on the selected objects extents ?

Comment: Num /, with Local View at the corner

Comment: If you try `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')` in local view and the object is selected afterwards, it means it is in local view. Doesn't it ? Obviously this wouldn't scale well with thousands of objects

Comment: No, that doesn't work because the target 3D-view area might be hidden

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it's hidden ? It might be targeting an area in another workspace ?

Comment: Yes, this example is correct

Comment: Have you tried overriding the operator ? `other_area = next(a for a in bpy.data.workspaces["my_other_workspace"].screens[0].areas if a.type == "VIEW_3D")` then `bpy.ops.object.select_all({"area": other_area}, action='SELECT')`

Comment: Even `visible_in_viewport_get()` returns `false` for all objects in the viewport, it's a shame. I would wait until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Wow, I've added it to bug