# about getting visible objects in local view?

Tags: scripting

No offence intended, this is Google Translate:
I don't understand why you guys are closing my question, and I don't understand where my question and that link are duplicates

`local_view_get()` always returns `False`. This bug seems to be two years old.

this is what i do now:

```py
def get_visible_objs(context, is_local=False):
    objects = context.scene.objects
    objs = [obj for obj in objects if obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.visible_get()]
    if is_local:
        backup_select_objs = [obj for obj in objects if obj.select_get()]
        backup_active_obj = context.active_object
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        objs = [obj for obj in objs if obj.select_get()]
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        for o in backup_select_objs:
            o.select_set(True)
        context.view_layer.objects.active = backup_active_obj

    return objs
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: It's already reported as a bug and not resolved yet https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/95197

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it is a bug and a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251743/how-to-get-a-list-of-objects-thats-currently-in-local-view

Answer (score 0):

Discovered by accident, don't know if it's reliable:

```py
def execute(self, context):
    objs = [obj.name for obj in context.scene.objects if obj.visible_get()]
    print(objs)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Directly using `[obj.name for obj in context.scene.objects if obj.visible_get()]` in the script editing window can only get all objects, but in the plug-in, you can get the objects visible in the local view