# How to check if an object is in a local view?

Tags: scripting

I found a lot of places and mentioned that this is a bug, and I have tried it.

such as: [How to get a list of objects that's currently in Local View?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251743/how-to-get-a-list-of-objects-thats-currently-in-local-view)

`C.object.local_view_get(space)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Test version: blender 3.4.1

Fortunately, I accidentally discovered the solution:

Tips from this:

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/custom-collection-property-on-spaceview3d-type-creates-a-tuple/11746/4

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

def get_view_regions(context):
    screen = context.screen
    view_region = None
    view_region_3d = None
    view_space = None
    for a in screen.areas:
       if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
            view_region_3d = a.spaces[0].region_3d
            view_space = a.spaces[0]
            for reg in a.regions[:]:
                if reg.type == "WINDOW":
                    view_region = reg
                    break
            break
    return view_region, view_region_3d, view_space

    
region, rv3d, space = get_view_regions(C)

deg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

ob = bpy.data.objects["obj_in_local"]
# ob = bpy.context.active_object

print(ob.evaluated_get(deg).local_view_get(space))
```

​
Successfully printed "True"